# How to make a JS function not self-invoke?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have issues with the confirm() function. It seems to ignore the `setTimeout()` function and invokes itself immediately.

I want the function to wait until the 600 seconds is done before invoking.

```js
function stillThere () { 
    if(confirm("Your session has expired. Are you still here?")){
     //Continue
    } else{
     window.location.href = "../logout.php";
    }
}

setTimeout(stillThere, 600);
```

Comment: It does invoke after `setTimeout`

Comment: You are setting 600 ms, not 600 second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout parameter for `setTimeout` is number in milliseconds

```js
function stillThere (){ 
    if(confirm("Your session has expired. Are you still here?")){
        //Continue
    }else{
     window.location.href = "../logout.php";
    }
}

// 1 second = 1000 ms
// 600 seconds = 600000 ms
setTimeout(stillThere, 600000);
```

Comment: Haha! I cant believe myself! Thank you that solved it!